# dataTaskWithURL for dummies

Tags: semaphore, nsurlsession, swift3

I keep learning iDev but I still can't deal with http requests.
It seems to be crazy, but everybody whom I talk about synchronous requests do not understand me. Okay, it's really important to keep on a background queue as much as it possible to provide smooth UI. But in my case I load JSON data from server and I need to use this data immediately. 
The only way I achieved it are semaphores. Is it okay? Or I have to use smth else? I tried NSOperation, but in fact I have to many little requests so creating each class for them for me seems to be not easy-reading-code.

```
func getUserInfo(userID: Int) -> User {
    var user = User()
    let linkURL = URL(string: "https://server.com")!
    let session = URLSession.shared
    let semaphore = DispatchSemaphore(value: 0)
    let dataRequest = session.dataTask(with: linkURL) { (data, response, error) in
        let json = JSON(data: data!)
        user.userName = json["first_name"].stringValue
        user.userSurname = json["last_name"].stringValue
        semaphore.signal()
    }
    dataRequest.resume()
    semaphore.wait(timeout: DispatchTime.distantFuture)
    return user
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You wrote that people don't understand you, but on the other hand it reveals that you don't understand how asynchronous network requests work.

For example imagine you are setting an alarm for a specific time.

Now you have two options to spend the following time.

1. Do nothing but sitting in front of the alarm clock and wait until the alarm occurs. Have you ever done that? Certainly not, but this is exactly what you have in mind regarding the network request.
2. Do several useful things ignoring the alarm clock until it rings. That is the way how asynchronous tasks work.

In terms of a programming language you need a completion handler which is called by the network request when the data has been loaded. In Swift you are using a closure for that purpose.

---

For convenience declare an enum with associated values for the `success` and `failure` cases and use it as the return value in the completion handler

```
enum RequestResult {
  case Success(User), Failure(Error)
}
```

Add a completion handler to your function including the error case. **It is highly recommended to handle always the error parameter of an asynchronous task.** When the data task returns it calls the completion closure passing the `user` or the `error` depending on the situation.

```
func getUserInfo(userID: Int, completion:@escaping (RequestResult) -> ())  {

  let linkURL = URL(string: "https://server.com")!
  let session = URLSession.shared
  let dataRequest = session.dataTask(with: linkURL) { (data, response, error) in
    if error != nil {
      completion(.Failure(error!))
    } else {

      let json = JSON(data: data!)
      var user = User()
      user.userName = json["first_name"].stringValue
      user.userSurname = json["last_name"].stringValue
      completion(.Success(user))
    }
  }
  dataRequest.resume()
}
```

Now you can call the function with this code:

```
getUserInfo(userID: 12) { result in
  switch result {
  case .Success(let user) :
    print(user)
    // do something with the user

  case .Failure(let error) :
    print(error)
    // handle the error
  }
}
```

In practice the point in time right after your `semaphore` and the `switch result` line in the completion block is exactly the same.

**Never use semaphores as an alibi not to deal with asynchronous patterns**

I hope the alarm clock example clarifies how asynchronous data processing works and why it is much more efficient to get notified (active) rather than waiting (passive).

Answer (score -1):

Don't try to force network connections to work synchronously.  It invariably leads to problems.  Whatever code is making the above call could potentially be blocked for up to 90 seconds (30 second DNS timeout + 60 second request timeout) waiting for that request to complete or fail.  That's an eternity.  And if that code is running on your main thread on iOS, the operating system will kill your app outright long before you reach the 90 second mark.

Instead, design your code to handle responses asynchronously.  Basically:

- Create data structures to hold the results of various requests, such as obtaining info from the user.
- Kick off those requests.
- When each request comes back, check to see if you have all the data you need to do something, and then do it.

For a really simple example, if you have a method that updates the UI with the logged in user's name, instead of:

```
[self updateUIWithUserInfo:[self getUserInfoForUser:user]];
```

you would redesign this as:

```
[self getUserInfoFromServerAndRun:^(NSDictionary *userInfo) {
    [self updateUIWithUserInfo:userInfo];
}];
```

so that when the response to the request arrives, it performs the UI update action, rather than trying to start a UI update action and having it block waiting for data from the server.

If you need two things—say the userInfo and a list of books that the user has read, you could do:

```
[self getUserInfoFromServerAndRun:^(NSDictionary *userInfo) {
    self.userInfo = userInfo;
    [self updateUI];
}];
[self getBookListFromServerAndRun:^(NSDictionary *bookList) {
    self.bookList = bookList;
    [self updateUI];
}];
...
(void)updateUI
{
    if (!self.bookList) return;
    if (!self.userInfo) return;

    ...
}
```

or whatever.  Blocks are your friend here.  :-)

Yes, it's a pain to rethink your code to work asynchronously, but the end result is much, much more reliable and yields a much better user experience.

Comment: Considering OP is new to iDev, it's probably safe to assume he is new to the languages as well. His question is tagged as Swift 3, so I recommend updating this answer to Swift. While for us it may be pretty easy to convert the code between Obj-C and Swift, it may not be the case with newcomers.

Comment: If I knew Swift, I would have written it in Swift.  Feel free to submit an edit.